# deleting random words from html page

Tags: javascript, html

I created a javascript program that prints element from my array one by one when you click on the title "click here" , my problem here is that tried to implement a function that deletes a random word from the html page when you click on the words printed previously but it printing other words instead, how can i create a function that removes words printed previously ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>function JavaScript</title>
   <script >
var k = 0;
var ph = ["red ","blue","black","green","yellow"];
function text(){

     if(k < ph.length ){

         document.getElementById("test").innerText+="  "+ ph[k];
            k++;
    }

}

function deleteWord(){

  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

   document.getElementById("test").innerText+="  "+ ph[number];



}
   </script>




</head>

<body>

<h1 onclick="text();">Click here</h1>

<span id="test" onclick="deleteWord();"></span>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("test").innerText = document.getElementById("test").innerText.replace(ph[number],"");`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteWord(){
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  document.getElementById("test").innerText+="  "+ ph[number];
}
```

Your problem is that the += operator appends `"  "+ ph[number]` after the current value of the string.

To replace instead, use the = operator to assign a new value. since you want to delete, just use an empty string.

```
  document.getElementById("test").innerText = "";
```

As a side note it is unusual to store multiple spaces in your string. If you are trying to move the contents around, you should probably consider setting the `padding-left` CSS property instead.

edit: if you don't want to lose the entire contents of the element, you can replace the last part of the string:

```
  document.getElementById("test").innerText.replace(/   .*$/,"");
```

Comment: i tried document.getElementById("test").innerText = ""; but it removes all the words printed before

Comment: see my edit above, it is a regex that matches three spaces in a row plus any following characters and replaces them with an empty string

Comment: You may find that a better design is to create an entirely new element with the color string. Use javascript to insert it into the DOM adjacent to its sibing, and style it with css.